# Understanding Model.from_db() in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I was reading [Django Official Doc for Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading), it reads:

> ##### classmethod Model.from_db(db, field_names, values)¶
>
> The `from_db()` method can be used to customize model instance creation when loading from the database.
>
> The `db` argument contains the database alias for the database the model is loaded from, `field_names` contains the names of all loaded fields, and `values` contains the loaded values for each field in `field_names`. The `field_names` are in the same order as the `values`. If all of the model’s fields are present, then `values` are guaranteed to be in the order `__init__()` expects them. That is, the instance can be created by `cls(*values)`. If any fields are deferred, they won’t appear in `field_names`. In that case, assign a value of `django.db.models.DEFERRED` to each of the missing fields.

I am completely lost when reading above.

- 1st perception: **"when loading from the database":** for me, `loading` means reading / retrieving data from database, which means the `model instance` already exists or is created and stored in DB.
- 2nd perception: **"be used to customize model instance creation"**, as well as the 2nd paragraph all makes me feel that this `from_db()` is for `model instance` creation, which conflicts with my 1st perception.

**Q: Can someone please share why, when and how we use `from_db()` in Django ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After making a database query, Django will create model objects. It does this by calling the [**`.from_db(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading). If the query thus returns two records with as first record `{'id': 14, 'name': 'foo'}`, and as second record `{'id': 25, 'name': 'bar'}`, it will call the `.from_db(…)` method twice with `SomeModel.from_db('db-alias', ['id', 'name'], [14, 'foo'])`, and `SomeModel.from_db('db-alias', ['id', 'name'], [25, 'bar'])`. This method is thus used to *convert* database data in model objects.

If you thus wish to customize how to convert data retrieved from the database, you can override the method, and for example pre-process the data in the parameters, or post-process the instance that is constructed.

Comment: @Yantian: yes, the two do not have the same liftetime. You can also make model objects that you do not (immediately) save to the database, for example to create a model object, and run some calculation, but never store it at the database side.

Comment: I thought `model instance` and `DB Record` were the same thing, and they had same period of lifetime. I were wrong, they are completely different things. `DB Record` is alive since it is created and stored in DB, until deletion. However, `model instance` is alive (born/created) when applications access/retrieve records from DB and consume them in the form of `model instance`.
**In summary, DB only understands raw records, while applications only understand `model instance`.**

Comment: I have a question... If you create a `QuerySet` that has say 1000 records, are the model instances created by `from_db` at each iteration of a loop on the `QuerySet` iterable, or are all the model objects created at the beginning of the loop? So say you only loop over 10 records and break the loop, only 10 are instantiated? And if I were to slice a queryset, they wouldn't instantiate until each iteration on the sliced items? (And I suspect in either case, if you convert a QuerySet to a list, then they would all be instantiated?

Comment: @hepcat72: yes, all items are instantiated one-by-one: you can see this [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/query.py#L120C37-L123), but it will not make a query for each item. If you convert it to a list, all will be instantiated yes. But converting these to a list is often *not* a good idea, a `QuerySet` is more flexible than a list, since it can do a lot of post-processing, etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm not converting to a list. I just wanted to make sure I understood how it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Model data exists as rows in the DB, when this data is retrieved from the DB via queries the raw data has to be converted into model instances, `Model.from_db` is the method that performs this conversion.

> 1st perception: "when loading from the database": for me, loading means reading / retrieving data from database, which means the model instance already exists or is created and stored in DB.

This is almost correct, model **data** exists in the database, model **instances** are created by this method when that data is queried

> 2nd perception: "be used to customize model instance creation", as well as the 2nd paragraph all makes me feel that this from_db() is for model instance creation, which conflicts with my 1st perception.

This is correct, `Model.from_db` is for instance creation and can be overridden to customise that process